# ADO.NET global OnBeforeExecute event

Tags: .net, ado.net, compact-framework

How can I check if connection still live is before every connection executed (also global OnBeforeExecute event handler) or I need to create global exception handler "error reading data from the connection"

Answer (score 0):

The best I've found is you actually have to try to establish a connection.

Here's the code I have stored:

```
 private const int RETRY = 3;

 public bool Reachable(Uri Address, string responseExpected) {
   for (int i = 0; i < RETRY; i++) {
     try {
       WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Address);
       req.Method = "GET";
       using (WebResponse rsvp = req.GetResponse()) {
         using (Stream s = rsvp.GetResponseStream()) {
           using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s)) {
             string text = r.ReadToEnd();
             r.Close();
             if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseExpected)) || (-1 < text.IndexOf(responseExpected))) {
               return true;
             }
           }
         }
       }
     } catch (Exception err) {
#if DEBUG
       Debug.WriteLine("Url: " + Address.ToString());
       Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
#endif
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```